# is there a way to execute a MySQL procedure automatically after server is up

Tags: mysql

I need to run a MySQL command every time the MYSQL server is up
I search for a start-up event or hooks but didn't find anything,
anyone knows the way to do it?

Comment: There is no such event or hook. Your best bet is to start mysql via a n external program or shell script that will execute an sql statement once the mysql process is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Server supports a configuration file directive [init_file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_file).

> this variable names a file containing SQL statements to be read and executed during the startup process.

Basically, it's like your `.bash_profile` is for Bash shell instances. In that it contains commands that are executed once at the startup.

For example using `init_file` is required for enabling performance_schema instruments and consumers at startup, because that must be done with `UPDATE` statements at runtime, not with configuration file directives.

Comment: I'm using some memory tables for speed(have a lot of reads and write on these tables).if the server restart I need to fill this table with default values from another table, is it possible with the init file?  or just the configurations that are mentioned in the docs

Comment: I haven't done that specific case, but I would expect there's a way to do it. I think you need to do some prototyping to see if it meets your needs.